# Neo4j independent selection over several match clauses

Tags: database, neo4j, match, movie, nosql

I want to select with neo4j the users, the amount of action movies they watched and how many of this action movies from each user where directed by Roland Emmerich.

I tried in various forms this query:

```
match (u:User)-[:watched]->(m:Movie)-[belongs_to]->       
(Category{category_name:"Action"}) with count(m) as actionMovies, u 
match (m:Movie)<-[directed]-(Director{director_name:"Roland Emmerich"})
return u, count(m) as MoviesFromRE, actionMovies
```

But the query execution never finishes. So I assume I'm doing something like a cross join.

Actually I expect to have the first count independent of the second since its already calculated when compiler comes to the second match clause.

Here is the relevant db view

[image: Overview of used database (Movies)]

Thanks for any suggestions and helps

Ok after get rid of the typos and including Movies in with clause:

```
match (u:User)-[:watched]->(m:Movie)-[:belongs_to]->      
(:Category{category_name:"Action"}) with count(m) as actionMovies, u, m
match (m)<-[:directed]-(:Director{director_name:"Roland Emmerich"})
return u, count(m) as MoviesFromRE, actionMovies order by u.user_name
```

Now I get for actionMovies always 1. I think its because I group now in first with clause by Movies. I think I need a way to take the Movies from the first clause to the second but not group my first result by them.

Comment: You have a few strange things in your query, unsure if they're typos when pasting it here, or if they exist in the queries you are trying to run. Remember that relationship types are preceded by a `:`, but `belongs_to` and `directed` in your queries are not, meaning they are variables matching to any type of relationship. Similarly, `Director` in your query is not a label (no `:`), so it's a variable matching to any node with a `director_name` property set to "Roland Emmerich". Similar with `Category` too.

Comment: Also, your second match is entirely disconnected from your first. Assuming that the relationship and Director node are fixed up so they're not variables, you are asking for all movies directed by Roland Emmerich, and that has no relation whatsoever to movies watched by a user, it will be constant to the number of movies Roland Emmerich directed. This is because the "m" variable bound to :Movies is not the same "m" as your first match (it wasn't preserved across your WITH)

Comment: @InverseFalcon I get rid of my typos and posted the new code with your suggestion of the with clause. Sadly I'm getting a wrong result since action Movies are now always 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are always getting 1 for `actionMovies` is in this clause:

```
WITH COUNT(m) AS actionMovies, u, m
```

That clause is saying (in part): "count the number of `m` nodes for every unique pair of `u` and `m` nodes". That count must always be 1.

This query should work better:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:watched]->(am:Movie)-[:belongs_to]->(:Category{category_name:"Action"})
WITH u, COLLECT(am) AS ams
UNWIND ams AS m
OPTIONAL MATCH (m)<-[dir:directed]-(:Director{director_name:"Roland Emmerich"})
RETURN u, COUNT(dir) AS MoviesFromRE, SIZE(ams) AS actionMovies
ORDER BY u.user_name;
```

Comment: I think that OPTIONAL MATCH might throw off your COUNT(m) in the return, as it will not affect the number of rows. I think you'll need a tweak to get this one to work.

Comment: @InverseFalcon Nice catch. Pretty subtle. Removed `OPTIONAL` from the second `MATCH`.

Comment: I'm not sure if that will work either, actually. Because it's now a MATCH, it will eliminate rows with movies that aren't directed by Roland Emmerich, so any user who has not watched one of these Roland Emmerich directed films will not appear in the result set. Maybe eliminate the MATCH and use `SIZE( (m)<-[:directed]-(:Director{director_name:"Roland Emmerich"}) )`. Alternately a FILTER might work well with some changes to the query.

Comment: @InverseFalcon Got me again :-). OK, I believe I have fixed it. I have changed it back to an `OPTIONAL MATCH` and I now `COUNT(dir)` instead of `COUNT(m)`. Pretty subtle issue, but this illustrates how important it is to thoroughly test Cypher code. Thanks for keeping me honest.

Comment: Looks good! And no problem, I'm sure you'll have opportunity to return the favor on some of my future slipups!

Comment: @cybersam What is if [dir:directed] is not unique? I now it would be stupid but I think it's possible.

Comment: A :directed relationship to :Director Roland Emmerich should be unique for a movie, unless there's bad data in the db where there's a duplicate :directed relationship to the same director (which should never happen if you've been using MERGE to create your relationships). The only other possibility for duplicates is if the :Movie node appears multiple times in the collection, which would only happen with bad data (duplicate relationships for a movie belonging to the action category, or multiple :watched relationships from a user to the same movie).